# Oracle SQL to generate Random unique values for specific column for those rows which are currently having null value for that column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I have a Table

```
ID       EMP_ID       EMP_NAME
--       ------       --------
43       001          SMITH
87       002          JOHN
NULL     003          MARK
98       004          ADAM
NULL     005          WILLY
NULL     006          RICKY
89       007          JOEY
```

I need to update the ID column for NULL values with randomly generated integers.

I have tried PL/SQL for this and that was working but it seems if SQL can do this in efficient way.

Comment: How are you doing it through PL/SQL? Do you have execute permission on the `dbms_random` package? (And shouldn't your IDs be coming from a sequence. rather than being random? How will you avoid clashes, and how will you pick an ID for your next new employee?)

Comment: yes I have permission on dbms_random package. Actually I have to keep this ID random to prevent the guess of ID, so can't use sequence

Comment: @AlexPoole To avoid clashes.. I seed dbms_random with rowid every time before update with random value.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner For this example I have kept it number(3) else it is varchar2(7) but I am not getting how you can get solution from knowing the range of emo_id..

Comment: Sorry I confused the IDs. So ID is number(2), right?

Comment: Yes, its number(2) for this question only. For my real scenario its number(10).

Comment: For number(2) you could simply generate all numbers from 1 to 99, remove the IDs used and pick one of the remaining numbers randomly. For number(10) and possibly millions of records already in the table, this seems much less feasible. And it seems strange you need to fill gaps every now and then. This sounds more like a one time job, for which you could use what you already have. Plus a trigger generating an ID on insert.

Comment: For my scenario, your suggestion would work fine. Thanks @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  ID       NUMBER(3,0),
  EMP_ID   CHAR(3),
  EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT 43,   '001', 'SMITH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 87,   '002', 'JOHN'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, '003', 'MARK'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98,   '004', 'ADAM'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, '005', 'WILLY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, '006', 'RICKY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 89,   '007', 'JOEY'  FROM DUAL;
```

**Update 1 - Random Values**:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET    id = SYS.DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 0, 99 )
WHERE  id IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

**Results**:

```
        ID EMP_ID EMP_NAME 
---------- ------ ----------
        43 001    SMITH      
        87 002    JOHN       
        55 003    MARK       
        98 004    ADAM       
        65 005    WILLY      
        54 006    RICKY      
        89 007    JOEY
```

**Update 2 - Sequential Values**:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE rowids_tt IS TABLE OF ROWID;
  rowids rowids_tt;
  maxid table_name.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT ROWID
  BULK COLLECT INTO rowids
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  ID IS NULL
  FOR UPDATE OF ID;

  SELECT COALESCE( MAX(id), 0 )
  INTO   maxid
  FROM   table_name;

  FOR i IN 1 .. rowids.COUNT LOOP
    UPDATE table_name t
    SET    t.id = maxid + i
    WHERE  t.ROWID = rowids(i);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

**Results**:

```
        ID EMP_ID EMP_NAME 
---------- ------ ----------
        43 001    SMITH      
        87 002    JOHN       
        99 003    MARK       
        98 004    ADAM       
       100 005    WILLY      
       101 006    RICKY      
        89 007    JOEY
```

Comment: I think, the Update 1 will clash in some cases with existing ID values as the random generated number has no seeds.